# Yield with NSThread?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa-touch, nsthread, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperationQueue and I want to cancel *some* operations. Therefore I iterate over the operation and cancel some tasks. At another point in the code which is executed subsequent in the same (UI) thread I check how many operations are in the queue. Even if I cancel *all* operations I get never 0. I guess the operations need to process the cancel properly. Therefore I would need some kind of "yield" function called in my UI thread after canceling. Is there a way to do that in Cocoa Touch?

My rather hackish solution is after cancel is:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
```

Any idea how to make that nicer?

Thanks,
Lars